# about implementing a multi linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a project which is similar to an address book. Firstly we have a number of students in a text file. I am going to implement a multi linked list which this list have 2 head+tail pointer (head+tail pointer for name,surname). These pointers show the same list but different locations because I am adding the nodes in ascending order and use double pointers to print the list backwards. The problem is I implemented the list by adding nodes by name and surname and the operation goes successfully when I insert another one. But I realized that when I deleted a node by her/his "name" and print the list again the student doesn't exist, but when I print the list by "surname" the student does exist. Then I recognize that I was implemented two separate linked lists. I was told to implement only ONE add and remove function. But how can I add a node by its first name pointers and surname pointers together? I hope I explained my issue understandably. Here are my blocks of code.

My structures:

```
typedef struct node {
    int birth_date;
    int zipcode;
    int phone_num;
    char first_name[50];
    char last_name[50];
    char city[50];
    char address[50];
    char email_addr[50];

    struct node* fn_next;
    struct node* fn_pre;
    struct node* ln_next;
    struct node* ln_pre;
    struct node* birdat_next;
    struct node* birdat_pre;
} NODE;

typedef struct {
    int fn_count;
    int ln_count;

    NODE* fn_head;
    NODE* ln_head;

    NODE* fn_tail;
    NODE* ln_tail;
}LIST;
```

The code block where I read the file line by line and call the add functions:

```
while ( !feof(myfile) ) {
    NODE* pnew_stu;

    if( !(pnew_stu = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE))) ) {
        printf("ERROR NOT ENOUGH MEMORY!!!\n");
        exit(100);
    }

    fscanf(myfile,"%s", &(pnew_stu->first_name) );
    fscanf(myfile,"%s", &(pnew_stu->last_name) );
    fscanf(myfile,"%s", &(pnew_stu->email_addr) );
    fscanf(myfile,"%d", &(pnew_stu->phone_num) );
    fscanf(myfile,"%s", &(pnew_stu->address) );
    fscanf(myfile,"%s", &(pnew_stu->city) );
    fscanf(myfile,"%d", &(pnew_stu->zipcode) );

    add_Node(list,pnew_stu);
}
```

And finally my add functions:

```
void add_fn_Node(LIST* list, NODE* pnew_stu) {
    NODE* temp = list->fn_head;

    if( list->fn_head == NULL ) {
        pnew_stu->fn_next = list->fn_head;
        pnew_stu->fn_pre = list->fn_head;

        list->fn_head = pnew_stu;
        list->fn_count = 1;
        return;
    }
    else {
        if ( (strcmp( pnew_stu->first_name, temp->first_name )) <= 0 ) { // Basa Ekleme Kosulu
            pnew_stu->fn_next = temp;
            pnew_stu->fn_pre = temp->fn_pre;
            temp->fn_pre = pnew_stu;

            list->fn_head = pnew_stu;
            list->fn_count++;   
            return;
        }
        else {
            while ( temp->fn_next != NULL ) { // Ortaya Ekleme Kosulu
                if ( (strcmp( pnew_stu->first_name, temp->first_name ) >= 0 ) && (strcmp( pnew_stu->first_name, temp->fn_next->first_name) < 0)) {
                    pnew_stu->fn_next = temp->fn_next;
                    pnew_stu->fn_pre = temp;
                    temp->fn_next->fn_pre = pnew_stu;
                    temp->fn_next = pnew_stu;

                    list->fn_count++;
                    return;
                }

                temp = temp->fn_next;
            }
            if ( temp->fn_next == NULL ) { // Sona Ekleme Kosulu
                temp->fn_next = pnew_stu;
                pnew_stu->fn_pre = temp;
                pnew_stu->fn_next = NULL;

                list->fn_tail = pnew_stu;
                list->fn_count++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void add_ln_Node(LIST* list, NODE* pnew_stu) {
    NODE* temp = list->ln_head;

    if( list->ln_head == NULL ) {
        pnew_stu->ln_next = list->ln_head;
        pnew_stu->ln_pre = list->ln_head;

        list->ln_head = pnew_stu;
        list->ln_count = 1;
        return;
    }
    else {
        if ( (strcmp( pnew_stu->last_name, temp->last_name )) <= 0 ) { // Basa Ekleme Kosulu
            pnew_stu->ln_next = temp;
            pnew_stu->ln_pre = temp->ln_pre;
            temp->ln_pre = pnew_stu;

            list->ln_head = pnew_stu;
            list->ln_count++;
            return;
        }
        else {
            while ( temp->ln_next != NULL ) { // Ortaya Ekleme Kosulu
                if ( (strcmp( pnew_stu->last_name, temp->last_name ) >= 0 ) && (strcmp( pnew_stu->last_name, temp->ln_next->last_name) < 0)) {
                    pnew_stu->ln_next = temp->ln_next;
                    pnew_stu->ln_pre = temp;
                    temp->ln_next->ln_pre = pnew_stu;
                    temp->ln_next = pnew_stu;

                    list->ln_count++;

                    return;
                }
                temp = temp->ln_next;
            }
            if ( temp->ln_next == NULL ) { // Sona Ekleme Kosulu
                temp->ln_next = pnew_stu;
                pnew_stu->ln_pre = temp;
                pnew_stu->ln_next = NULL;

                list->ln_tail = pnew_stu;

                list->ln_count++;

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My delete functions:

```
void del_fn_name(LIST* list, char* str_key) {
    NODE* temp;

    int num,counter=1,flag;

    temp = list->fn_head;

    if( list->fn_head == NULL ) {
        printf("The list is EMPTY!!!\n");
        return;
    }

    flag = search_fn(list,str_key);

    if ( flag ) {
        printf("Enter the number of student you want to delete : ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if( strcmp( list->fn_head->first_name, str_key ) == 0 ) { // Bastan Silme Kosulu
            if( num == counter ) {
                list->fn_head->fn_next->fn_pre = list->fn_head;
                list->fn_head = list->fn_head->fn_next;
                free(list->fn_head);

                printf("%s is deleted and the new header is %s\n", str_key, list->fn_head->first_name );
                return;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        temp = temp->fn_next;

        while ( temp->fn_next != NULL ) {
            if( strcmp( temp->first_name, str_key ) == 0 ) {
                if( num == counter ) {
                    temp->fn_pre->fn_next = temp->fn_next;
                    temp->fn_next->fn_pre = temp->fn_pre;
                    free(temp);
                    printf("%s deleted at between %s  and  %s\n", str_key, temp->fn_pre->first_name, temp->fn_next->first_name);
                    return;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            temp = temp->fn_next;
        }

        if( temp->fn_next == NULL ) { // Sondan Silme Kosulu
            if( strcmp(temp->first_name, str_key) == 0 ) {
                if( num == counter ) {
                    list->fn_tail = temp->fn_pre;
                    temp->fn_pre->fn_next = NULL;
                    free(temp);
                    printf("%s deleted at the end and new tail is %s \n", str_key, list->fn_tail->first_name );
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

void del_ln_name(LIST* list, char* str_key) {
    NODE* temp;
    int num,counter=1,flag;
    temp = list->ln_head;

    if( list->ln_head == NULL ) {
        printf("The list is EMPTY!!!\n");
        return;
    }

    flag = search_ln(list,str_key);

    if ( flag ) {
        printf("Enter the number of student you want to delete : ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        if( strcmp( list->ln_head->last_name, str_key ) == 0 ) { // Bastan Silme Kosulu
            if( num == counter ) {
                temp->ln_next->ln_pre = list->ln_head;
                list->ln_head = temp->ln_next;
                free(temp);

                printf("%s is deleted and the new header is %s\n", str_key, list->ln_head->last_name );
                return;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        temp = temp->ln_next;
        while ( temp->ln_next != NULL ) {
            if( strcmp( temp->last_name, str_key ) == 0 ) {
                if( num == counter ) {
                    temp->ln_pre->ln_next = temp->ln_next;
                    temp->ln_next->ln_pre = temp->ln_pre;
                    free(temp);

                    printf("%s deleted at between %s  and  %s\n", str_key, temp->ln_pre->last_name, temp->ln_next->last_name);
                    return;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            temp = temp->ln_next;
        }

        if( temp->ln_next == NULL ) { // Sondan Silme Kosulu
            printf("The last item %s second last item %s\n", temp->first_name, list->fn_tail->fn_pre->first_name);*/
            if( strcmp(temp->last_name, str_key) == 0 ) {
                if( num == counter ) {
                    list->ln_tail = temp->ln_pre;
                    temp->ln_pre->ln_next = NULL;
                    free(temp);

                    printf("%s deleted at the end and new tail is %s \n", str_key, list->ln_tail->last_name );
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The integers `flag` and `counter` are for deleting the duplicate students. For example, if there are three duplicates it asks me to which number of student I want to delete. So if I enter number 2 it deletes the second duplicate.

Comment: It sounds like your list will be ordered by one of the pointer types; i.e. name, but that your surname pointer will jump around inside your list. Ex: `Name` H -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 - NULL, and `Surname`: `H` -> 2 -> 0 -> 3 -> 1 -> NULL.

Comment: yes i said that i want to have one list and two different head pointers. so of course the name and surname will have different orders.

Comment: Yes, so you can add this all in one method; you simply insert in one list first, then reorder the second.

Comment: and the method is my question. how can i add a node with ordered by name and surname in one function_?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

print(search(type="cliente", codice=random.randrange(1000)))
print(find(type="cliente", codice=random.randrange(1000)))
import sys
sys.exit(1)

Your code seems a bit complex for what is needed but the idea is correct. I don't see any error in the insert method but it's quite hard to follow all this sort of copy'n paste program. You can have each students in several different lists at the same time, but I'd suggest using a different approach to avoiding all this duplication that makes very easy to introduce bugs.

### Data structure

You could abstract the idea of link and list:

```
typedef struct TList
{
    struct TLink *first, *last;
} List;

typedef struct TLink
{
    struct TStudent *student;
    struct TLink *prev, *next;
} Link;
```

The `List` structure is any of the three lists you need (first name, last name, birthdate) and `Link` is any of the links. See the following picture...

[image]

With this approach the code for inserting/removing a link in a list is shared with all link types (`first_name`, `last_name`, `age`). The price to pay is an extra pointer for each link and the need to write `link->student->first_name` instead of `link->first_name`.

### Link insertion/deletion

Adding a link to a list is something like

```
// Adds a new link before the link `before` or as last link
// if `before` is NULL
void addLink(List *list, Link *newlink, Link *before)
{
    newlink->next = before;
    newlink->prev = before ? before->prev : list->last;
    if (newlink->next) newlink->next->prev = newlink;
                  else list->last = newlink;
    if (newlink->prev) newlink->prev->next = newlink;
                  else list->first = newlink;
}
```

and removing a link from a list is something like

```
void removeLink(List *lists, Link *link)
{
    if (link->next) link->next->prev = link->prev;
               else list->last = link->prev;
    if (link->prev) link->prev->next = link->next;
               else list->first = link->next;
}
```

These two function can be used to manage lists/links of all three types (first_name, last_name and age) without any code duplication.

### Insertion of a Student object

With this approach the student object can have all the data and many links objects

```
typedef struct TStudent
{
    char first_name[NAMESIZE];
    char last_name[NAMESIZE};
    int age;
    Link first_name_link, last_name_link, age_link;
} Student;
```

For example to insert the student in order for the `first_name` list the code becomes

```
Student *newstudent = ...
...
Link *before = first_name_list.first;
while (before != NULL &&
       strcmp(newstudent->first_name,
              before->student->first_name) > 0)
{
    before = before->next;
}
addLink(&first_name_list,
        &newstudent->first_name_link,
        before);
```

Please note that this simple loop handles correctly all cases that in your code are instead handled separately with copy'n paste of similar statements (this is the first student inserted, the last, one in the middle).

The idea here is just to set the `before` node to the first in the list and keeping moving it to next student if the new one must be inserted after instead.

Of course the same kind of loop is needed to find the correct insertion point in the other two lists (`last_name_list` and `age_list`). Factoring out also the insertion point search would be possible by using function pointers.

### Deletion of a Student object

To delete a `Student` of course the student data must be removed from all the lists, in other words all three links must be removed. This however simply means calling three times the `removeLink` function:

```
 removeLink(&first_name_list, &student->first_name_link);
 removeLink(&last_name_list, &student->last_name_link);
 removeLink(&age_list, &student->age_link);
 free(student);
```

Comment: ok well could you tell me where i am doing wrong in my delete funcion. and don't understand why you send the addresses of firstname_name_list and newstudent->first_name_link_?. and here is my deletion code;

Comment: and i can't answer my own question cause i am new at this forum. it doesn't allow me : ). i posted my delete func. in my first message

Comment: The problem is that when you delete a student all of the links must be removed from the lists. See my edit.

Comment: ok mates i solved the issue. i had a problem in delete function and solved it with user6502 's suggestion. :) so thanks finally

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic answer, in C++, is simply to use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). It is meant exactly for the purpose of adding elements with various access paths (indexes) and keeping all indexes synchronized.

If you wish to reimplement the world, however, and if you are limited to C (since all the code you presented so far is C, despite the tag), then I do not know of any library that can provide this.

Generally speaking, the idea is simple enough, especially if a simple list is sufficient. As you noted in your node, you simply need a prev/next pair by index you wish to keep the node in.

Now, when adding a node, you first need to allocate it, then to locate the point of insertion in each of the index. If all are located, and no error occurs, then you insert it at the located point in each index, and the structure is now responsible for managing the memory.

Similarly, when removing a node, you first need to locate the node itself, then remove it from each of the index. Then either you return it to the caller (`pop`-like) or free it yourself.

Comment: well i don't know why user "staffman" changed the tag by "C++". but yes i work with C. actually the adding or removind functions are working correctly. the simple problem is i can't implement a single list which have two different headers as you can see (list->fn_head and list->ln_head) these pointers show different locations on a single list. but it doesn't working that way. i realized that i am creating two same but separete lists. so i try to add the nodes in one function. but i can't managed it. : ). this is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
void add_Node(LIST* list,NODE* pnew_stu){
    add_fn_Node(list,pnew_stu);
    add_ln_Node(list,pnew_stu);
}

void remove_Node(LIST* list, NODE* pdead_stu){
    if(pdead_stu->fn_next){
        pdead_stu->fn_next->fn_pre=pdead_stu->fn_pre;
    }
    if(pnew_stu->fn_pre){
        pdead_stu->fn_pre->fn_next=pdead_stu->fn_next;
    }
    if(pnew_stu->ln_next){
        pdead_stu->ln_next->ln_pre=pdead_stu->ln_pre;
    }
    if(pnew_stu->ln_pre){
        pdead_stu->ln_pre->fn_pre=pdead_stu->ln_next;
    }
    if(list->fn_head==pdead_stu){list->fn_head=pdead_stu->fn_next;}
    if(list->ln_head==pdead_stu){list->ln_head=pdead_stu->ln_next;}
    if(list->fn_tail==pdead_stu){list->fn_tail=pdead_stu->fn_pre;}
    if(list->ln_tail==pdead_stu){list->ln_tail=pdead_stu->ln_pre;}
    list->fn_count--;
    list->ln_count--;
}
```

Comment: well mate could you tell where is my fault then_?. and thanks for your help. i going to try it

Comment: I don't seem to see your particular error, but your code isn't very structured. You can see you need a search function to find dead_stu, but that's pretty easy. When I posted you had only 2 lists, now you have 3 you'd better use either 6502's solution or a macro-based solution(since you're a beginner use 6502's), as your code duplication is getting to bad (2x is acceptable, though looked down upon, 3x is unacceptable).